# There is a way to improve the execution time?

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access, findfirst

I'm developing a VBA code that is responsible for searching in a excel file the value of a cell (serial number) and its production start date. After that, its searches on a Access databse for that same serial number and writes on the especified column the date. 
The problem is that it's taking hours to end, because the excel and the database have more than 10000 rows...
The question is: there is a way that I can improve my code to run faster?

```
Private Sub Comando9_Click()
 Set db = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ConsultaNSerie", dbOpenDynaset)
 Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'appExcel.Visible = True
 appExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open "K:\EM HP - Comum\Planejamento de 
 Produção HP\CB\Planejamento de Produção_CB_FY19-20\Planejamento de 
 Produção_CB_FY19-20.xlsm"

 Dim Inicio_planejado As Variant
 Dim Numero_serie As String
 Dim SAP As String
 i = 9

 Dim fso As Object
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Dim Fileout As Object
 Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("K:\EM HP - Engenharia\02-Aplicação\11- 
 Controle de Projetos\Nserie_NoMatch.txt", True, True)

 Do
     SAP = appExcel.Sheets("Disjuntores").Columns("I").Rows(i).Value
     Numero_serie = appExcel.Sheets("Disjuntores").Columns("L").Rows(i).Value
     'MsgBox (Numero_serie)
     Inicio_planejado = 
     appExcel.Sheets("Disjuntores").Columns("T").Rows(i).Value

    If Inicio_planejado <> "" Then
        'MsgBox (Inicio_planejado)
        'quando for vazio, desconsiderar a celula
        'ThisWorkbook.Reg.FindFirst "[OF] = '" + cb_OF.Value + " '"
        db.FindNext "[NUMERO_SERIE] = '" + Numero_serie + " '"
        If db.NoMatch Then
            db.FindPrevious "[NUMERO_SERIE] = '" + Numero_serie + " '"
        ElseIf db.NoMatch Then
            Fileout.Write Numero_serie & "  "
            'MsgBox ("Número de série " + Numero_serie + " não encontrado")
        Else
            'Adicionar o valor de "Inicio_planejado" aos campos na coluna 
     "INICIO_FBR"
            db.Edit
            db![INICIO_FBR] = Inicio_planejado
            db.Update
            db.MoveNext
        End If
End If

i = i + 1

Loop Until appExcel.Sheets("Disjuntores").cells(i, 7) = ""

Fileout.Close
appExcel.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Such questions might be better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but please read their FAQ first!

Comment: Use `Range.AutoFilter` or at least use arrays to loop through memory as a start.

Comment: What is `db`? Please include all variable declarations and initializations in your code.

Comment: if you have access to access database, you could link the excel file as `linked table` and perform update on access table.

Comment: Using your code and some test data updating 10,000 rows takes about 60 seconds on my machine so is either or both the excel spreadsheet and the access database on a network drive ?

Comment: both of them are

Comment: I've edited with my entire code...

Comment: Is the problem solved ? I have an idea if you are interested. I'm assuming both database and workbook are on the same mapped network drive K:, is this correct ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't use `db.FindNext` and `db.FindPrevious` with the same search criterium. That makes no sense for your situation.

Use only `FindFirst`, and get rid of the `db.MoveNext`:

```
    db.FindFirst "[NUMERO_SERIE] = '" + Numero_serie + " '"
    If db.NoMatch Then
        Fileout.Write Numero_serie & "  "
    Else
        db.Edit
        db![INICIO_FBR] = Inicio_planejado
        db.Update
        ' Remove this, is is of no use:
        '--- db.MoveNext
    End If
```

2) In Access, edit the table `ConsultaNSerie` and add an **index** on `NUMERO_SERIE`.

Comment: how can I add an index?